# Display certain fields dependant on radio button select on page load

Tags: javascript, php

I am dragging data from a database and want to display different disabled form fields dependant on the selected radio button.

I have tried using onload="javascript:...." but it's not working.

HTML:

```
 <fieldset>
      <legend>Employment/Education Details</legend>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
         <label>Are you?<br>
         <input type="radio" onload="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="employed" id="employed" <?php if 
($employment_status=="employed") echo "checked"; ?> disabled><label for="employed">Employed</label>
         <input type="radio" onload="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="self_employed" id="self_employed"  <?php if 
($employment_status=="self_employed") echo "checked"; ?> disabled><label for="self_employed">Self Employed</label>
         <input type="radio" onload="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="student" id="student" <?php if 
($employment_status=="student") echo "checked"; ?> disabled><label for="student">Student</label>
         <input type="radio" onload="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="other" id="other" <?php if 
($employment_status=="other") echo "checked"; ?> disabled><label for="other">Other</label>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div id="college_nus" style="display:none">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>College or NUS Number
                  <input type="text" name="college_nus"  value="<?php echo $college_nus; ?>" disabled>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="employment_details" style="display:none">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employer Name
                  <input type="text" name="employment_company" value="<?php echo $employment_company; ?>" disabld>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Job Title
                  <input type="text" name="employment_title" value="<?php echo $employment_title; ?>" disabled>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employment Address
                  <textarea name="employment_address" rows="4" value="<?php echo $employment_address; ?>" disabled></textarea>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>
                     Occupation
                  <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $occupation; ?>" disabled>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employment Email
                  <input type="text" name="employment_email"  value="<?php echo $employment_email; ?>" disabled>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employment Phone
                  <input type="text" name="employment_phone"  value="<?php echo $employment_phone; ?>" disabled>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
```

Javascript:

```
function employmentCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('student').checked) {
        document.getElementById('college_nus').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('college_nus').style.display = 'none';

    if (document.getElementById('employed').checked || document.getElementById('self_employed').checked) {
        document.getElementById('employment_details').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('employment_details').style.display = 'none';

}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: By not working, do you mean you are getting an error message?

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit! It selects the correct radio button from what is in the database but it's not displaying the fields relevant to that radio button using javascript. It works fine when you are manually click on a radio button with a onclick but not onload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the function to window.onload and it worked fine. Here is a plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Pz2rKRg9geglgKhdJM4H?p=preview

Here is the function

```
window.onload = function(){
    if (document.getElementById('student').checked) {
        console.log("student");
        document.getElementById('college_nus').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('college_nus').style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('employed').checked ||  document.getElementById('self_employed').checked) {
        console.log("employed");
        document.getElementById('employment_details').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('employment_details').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I don't think there is an event of onload defined on the radio button object.

Thanks

Paras

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks @user886393